# html 5 video will not autoplay

Tags: html5-video

I have a video that should autoplay, but it will not.
I had it set up like this:

```
<video id="video" autoplay muted playsinline loop
    poster="http://res.cloudinary.com/situ-live/video/upload/f_auto/Situ-Sizzler-Web-Clip-v05-01_auvu5o.jpg"
    #video>
    <source
        src="http://res.cloudinary.com/situ-live/video/upload/f_auto/Situ-Sizzler-Web-Clip-v05-01_auvu5o.webm"
        type="video/webm">
    <source
        src="http://res.cloudinary.com/situ-live/video/upload/f_auto/Situ-Sizzler-Web-Clip-v05-01_auvu5o.mp4"
        type="video/mp4">
    <source
        src="http://res.cloudinary.com/situ-live/video/upload/f_auto/Situ-Sizzler-Web-Clip-v05-01_auvu5o.ogv"
        type="video/ogg">
</video>
```

As you can see, it's muted so according to [this document](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes) it should play, but it will not.
I tried to add a function to the **canplay** method, but when I do that I get this error:

> DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first.

which is what lead me to the document above.
Does anyone know how I can solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you just use the HTML you have in question have in  - the video plays just fine.

If you try to force it to play with JS - you'll get this error - as it is a way people try to get around blocking autoplay in the browser. for play() in JS to work, the user must first click somewhere on the page.

Answer (score -2):

by default in newer versions of browsers, because of the user experience and prevention of sudden playing of the video, sometimes `autoplay` attribute won't work.
you can just fix it by a line of javascript in the page load function:

```
document.getElementById("video").play();
```

that's it!

Comment: I already tried that, that's what is happening on the **canplay** event. But when I try to play the video I get the "play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first." error